# How to save spinner to saved/shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, spinner

I am able to save Strings in my saved preferences but having difficulty saving my spinner.

```
 public class Diet extends Activity {

  private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  Spinner spnCalorieRange;
```

Here is my onCreate:

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

String strAge = Integer.toString(age);
String strHeight = Integer.toString(height);
String strWeight = Integer.toString(weight);

name = loadSavedPreference("name");
strAge = loadSavedPreference("strAge");
strHeight = loadSavedPreference("strHeight");
strWeight = loadSavedPreference("strWeight");

etName.setText(name);
etAge.setText(strAge);
etHeight.setText(strHeight);
etWeight.setText(strWeight);
```

This is my Spinner in my onCreate:

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnCalorieRange); 
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Calorie_Range, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            long item = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
            String pos =spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("PREF_SPINNER", position).commit();
            if (item == 0){
                deficitPercentage = .05;
            }
            else if (item ==1)
            {
                deficitPercentage = .1;
            }
            else if (item ==2)
            {
                deficitPercentage = .15;    
            }
            else if (item ==3)
            {
                deficitPercentage = .2;
            }
            else if (item ==4)
            {
                deficitPercentage = .25;
            }
            else
            {
                deficitPercentage = .3;
            }
            //editor.putString("pos", pos);
            //editor.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

This is in my onCLick behind a button, where I'm saving the strings and spinner

```
 age = (int) Double.parseDouble(etAge.getText().toString());
        height = (int) Double.parseDouble(etHeight.getText().toString());
        weight = (int) Double.parseDouble(etWeight.getText().toString());


        //Save Preferences
        String strAge = Integer.toString(age);
        String strHeight = Integer.toString(height);
        String strWeight = Integer.toString(weight);

        name = etName.getText().toString();
        savePreference("name",name);

        strAge = etAge.getText().toString();
        savePreference("strAge",strAge);

        strHeight = etHeight.getText().toString();
        savePreference("strHeight",strHeight);

        strWeight = etWeight.getText().toString();
        savePreference("strWeight",strWeight);:
```

Comment: You are loading your spinner with an Array from resource file, so I would assume you don't want to save the complete data. Do you want to save currently selected item?

Comment: Why do you have two questions for one thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380863/how-to-save-spinner-as-shared-preference Marking duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save the actual spinner object to shared prefs, but you can save all of the values that make the spinner work its magic and next time you create the spinner, just apply those values

Answer (score 0):

In your `onItemSelected` place:

```
int spinnerPosition = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
saveSpinnerPosition(spinnerPosition);
```

**Save method**

```
public void saveSpinnerPosition(int position){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    prefEditor.putInt("spnCalorieRange",position); 
    prefEditor.apply();
}
```

**Load method**

```
public void loadSpinnerPosition{
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int position= sharedPreferences .getInt"spnCalorieRange",-1);
    if(spinnerValue > -1)

    // set the value of the spinner 
    spinner.setSelection(position);
}
```

To put spinners back to position, call `loadSpinnerPosition` in your `onCreate`

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Edit:**

because I noticed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601149/how-to-save-radio-button-status-to-saved-shared-preferences) is also your question, u can also do everything at **once**:

At the **top** of your activity:

```
int spinnerPosition;
```

In your `onItemSelected` place:

```
spinnerPosition = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

**Save method**

```
public void saveMethod(){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("Gender", radioSexButton.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("Male", rdoMale.isChecked());
    prefEditor.putInt("spnCalorieRange",spinnerPosition); 
    prefEditor.apply();
}
```

**Load method**

```
public void loadMethod(){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int position= sharedPreferences .getInt"spnCalorieRange",-1);
    radioSexButton.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Gender", false)); 
    rdoMale.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Male", false));

    if(spinnerValue > -1)

    // set the value of the spinner 
    spinner.setSelection(position);
}
```

**Then** call `saveMethod()` when u want to save all your states, and call `loadMethod()` when u wanna load all your states

Should help u out

Comment: Cool looks good, where should i put the save and load methods?

Comment: Doesn't matter, just somewhere in your class. for instance **beneath** your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Ok so it's almost sorted, only issue is that its not recognising "getDefaultSharedPreferences"

Comment: Change `getDefaultSharedPreference` to `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference`

Comment: Check my latest **edit** if u want to do all at once

Comment: Saving integer position is bad idea. What if spinner content changed in later update then you messed the whole perferences